# Text blocks in JOptionPane

Tags: java

The following code shows two labels with the same multiline html text. The labels
differ, however, in the way their text is defined: one as a usual string, the other
as a text block.
The labels are displayed as expected, namely without any difference.
The OptionPanes use the very same strings as the labels, but the text block
is not rendered properly. Any idea why? (java version "16")

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextBlocks extends JFrame {
  public static final long serialVersionUID = 100L;

  JButton b1, b2;
  String txt1, txt2;

  public TextBlocks() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 240);

    txt1= "<html>"+
        "<h3><font color=fuchsia>Caption</font></h3><font size=3>"+
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>"+
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore<br><br>"+ 
        "<h3>Topic 1</h3><font size=3>"+
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>"+
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>"+
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br><br>"+
        "<h3>Topic 2</h3><font size=3>"+
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>"+
        "sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>"+
        "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita-<br>"+
        "tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi</html>";
    JLabel lb= new JLabel(txt1);
    add(lb, BorderLayout.WEST);
    txt2= """
    <html><h3><font color=fuchsia>Caption</font></h3><font size=3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>
    sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore<br><br>
    <h3>Topic 1</h3><font size=3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>
    sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br><br>
    <h3>Topic 2</h3><font size=3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br>
    sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita-<br>
    tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi</html>
    """;
    lb= new JLabel(txt2);
    add(lb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel p= new JPanel();
    b1= new JButton("JOptionPane with text 1");
    ActionListener listener= new ActListener();
    b1.addActionListener(listener);
    p.add(b1);
    b2= new JButton("JOptionPane with text 2");
    b2.addActionListener(listener);
    p.add(b2);
    add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }


  static public void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(TextBlocks::new);
  }


  class ActListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      String buf= evt.getSource()==b1 ? txt1 : txt2;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextBlocks.this, buf, "Demo",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @Yassin. Compile and run the code. In the JOptionPane with text block the interpretation of the html tags is aborted and the tags themselves are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing carriage returns in `txt2` make the text block unmanageable by your `JOptionPane`, instead explicitly consider the text block as a one-liner by using `\` at the end of each line

```java
txt2 = """
        <html><h3><font color=fuchsia>Caption</font></h3><font size=3> \
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br> \
        sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore<br><br> \
        <h3>Topic 1</h3><font size=3> \
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br> \
        sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br> \
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br><br> \
        <h3>Topic 2</h3><font size=3> \
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit,<br> \
        sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br> \
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercita-<br> \
        tion ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi</html> \
        """;
```

This produces the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`JOptionPane` uses `JLabel` to render text and the latter is designed [to display a single line text](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) only. Thus the issue does not come from using text blocks, in fact if you add a newline to the `txt1` string, you will observe the same behavior.

However, a multiline text can be displayed  within `JLabel`, one must use html and avoid any newline symbols.

```
String example = """
  <html>
  <h1>Example</h1><br>
  <p>A line</p>
  </html> 
    """.replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: Thank you, Eugene. Still strange that the text block label is displayed nicely when in a JFrame, but broken when in a JOptionPane. - Unfortunately one can tick only one answer as correct, but your solution works as well.

Comment: You are welcome, your question was clear, interesting and it contained a minimal, reproducible example, way to go!